# wsl python works slow

Tags: python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux

i run flask app `FLASK_ENV=development flask run`

i haven't touched locally installed python for 2-3 months

unexpected behaviour:

1. server starts slowly than previously
2. usually with `FLASK_ENV=development` server reloads when files change(after file changed reloading will perform in 40-50 seconds)

i did:

1. re-install pythons(3.8,3.9)
2. re-install wsl(debian, ubuntu)

p.s. usually wsl command installs high distributive version, but today 09.12.2022 wsl command installs debian 9???

Answer (score -1):

problem have solved through switching to wsl version 1

p.s. reason to post this question - poke the problem for another developers